# C++ Single Layer Multi Output Perceptron Weird Behaviour

Tags: c++, machine-learning, neural-network, perceptron

Some background:

I wrote a single layer multi output perceptron class in C++.  It uses the typical WX + b discriminant function and allows for user-defined activation functions.  I have tested everything pretty throughly and it all seems to be working as I expect it to.  I noticed a small logical error in my code, and when I attempted to fix it the network performed much worse than before.  The error is as follows:

I evaluate the value at each output neuron using the following code:

```
output[i] =
          activate_(std::inner_product(weights_[i].begin(), weights_[i].end(),
                                       features.begin(), -1 * biases_[i]));
```

Here I treat the bias input as a fixed -1, but when I apply the learning rule to each bias, I treat the input as +1.

```
// Bias can be treated as a weight with a constant feature value of 1.
biases_[i] = weight_update(1, error, learning_rate_, biases_[i]);
```

So I attempted to fix my mistake by changing the call to weight_updated to be conistent with the output evaluation:

```
biases_[i] = weight_update(-1, error, learning_rate_, biases_[i]);
```

But doing so results in a 20% drop in accuracy!
I have been pulling my hair out for the past few days trying to find some other logical error in my code which might explain this strange behaviour, but have come up empty handed.  Can anyone with more knowledge than I provide any insight into this?  I have provided the entire class below for reference.  Thank you in advance.

```
#ifndef SINGLE_LAYER_PERCEPTRON_H
#define SINGLE_LAYER_PERCEPTRON_H

#include <cassert>
#include <functional>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
#include "functional.h"
#include "random.h"

namespace qp {
namespace rf {

namespace {

template <typename Feature>
double weight_update(const Feature& feature, const double error,
                     const double learning_rate, const double current_weight) {
  return current_weight + (learning_rate * error * feature);
}

template <typename T>
using Matrix = std::vector<std::vector<T>>;

}  // namespace

template <typename Feature, typename Label, typename ActivationFn>
class SingleLayerPerceptron {
 public:
  // For testing only.
  SingleLayerPerceptron(const Matrix<double>& weights,
                        const std::vector<double>& biases, double learning_rate)
      : weights_(weights),
        biases_(biases),
        n_inputs_(weights.front().size()),
        n_outputs_(biases.size()),
        learning_rate_(learning_rate) {}

  // Initialize the layer with random weights and biases in [-1, 1].
  SingleLayerPerceptron(std::size_t n_inputs, std::size_t n_outputs,
                        double learning_rate)
      : n_inputs_(n_inputs),
        n_outputs_(n_outputs),
        learning_rate_(learning_rate) {
    weights_.resize(n_outputs_);
    std::for_each(
        weights_.begin(), weights_.end(), [this](std::vector<double>& wv) {
          generate_back_n(wv, n_inputs_,
                          std::bind(random_real_range<double>, -1, 1));
        });

    generate_back_n(biases_, n_outputs_,
                    std::bind(random_real_range<double>, -1, 1));
  }

  std::vector<double> predict(const std::vector<Feature>& features) const {
    std::vector<double> output(n_outputs_);
    for (auto i = 0ul; i < n_outputs_; ++i) {
      output[i] =
          activate_(std::inner_product(weights_[i].begin(), weights_[i].end(),
                                       features.begin(), -1 * biases_[i]));
    }
    return output;
  }

  void learn(const std::vector<Feature>& features,
             const std::vector<double>& true_output) {
    const auto actual_output = predict(features);
    for (auto i = 0ul; i < n_outputs_; ++i) {
      const auto error = true_output[i] - actual_output[i];
      for (auto weight = 0ul; weight < n_inputs_; ++weight) {
        weights_[i][weight] = weight_update(
            features[weight], error, learning_rate_, weights_[i][weight]);
      }
      // Bias can be treated as a weight with a constant feature value of 1.
      biases_[i] = weight_update(1, error, learning_rate_, biases_[i]);
    }
  }

 private:
  Matrix<double> weights_;      // n_outputs x n_inputs
  std::vector<double> biases_;  // 1 x n_outputs
  std::size_t n_inputs_;
  std::size_t n_outputs_;
  ActivationFn activate_;
  double learning_rate_;
};

struct StepActivation {
  double operator()(const double x) const { return x > 0 ? 1 : -1; }
};

}  // namespace rf
}  // namespace qp

#endif /* SINGLE_LAYER_PERCEPTRON_H */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out...

My fix was indeed correct and the loss of accuracy was just a consequence of having a lucky (or unlucky) dataset.